# Python turtle project producing error: object has no attribute

Tags: python, class, python-imaging-library, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to complete a final project for my Python course. The requirements are as follows:

1. Use the concepts of object-based programming—classes, objects, and
   methods
2. Draw two-dimensional shape
3. Develop recursive algorithms to draw recursive shapes
4. Write a nested loop to process a two-dimensional grid

I have written some code but I am having trouble getting it to produce a result in the turtle screen:

```
import turtle
from PIL import Image
kel = turtle.Turtle()

class Draw_pattern(object):
    def __init__(self,posx,posy,size):
        self.posx = posx
        self.posy = posy
        self.size = size

    def draw_grid(self,initx, inity):
        # Drawing grid
        kel.penup()
        kel.color("black")
        for i in range(7):
            kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy)
            kel.pendown()
            kel.forward(self.size*6)
            self.posy = self.posy+self.size;
            self.posx = initx;
            kel.penup()

        self.posx = initx;
        self.posy = inity;
        kel.left(90)
        for i in range(7):
            kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy)
            kel.pendown()
            kel.forward(self.size*6)
            self.posx = self.posx+self.size;
            self.posy = inity;
            kel.penup()

def draw_shape(self,initx, inity):
    self.posx = initx;
    self.posy = inity;
# Drawing yellow portion
    kel.penup()
    kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy)
    kel.pendown()
    kel.fillcolor("yellow")
    kel.begin_fill()
    kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy+self.size*6)
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*6, self.posy+self.size*6)
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*6, self.posy)
    kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy)
    kel.end_fill()

# Drawing red portion
    kel.penup()
    kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy+self.size*2)
    kel.pendown()
    kel.fillcolor("red")
    kel.begin_fill()
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size, self.posy+self.size*3)
    kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy+self.size*4)
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*2, self.posy+self.size*4)
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*2, self.posy+self.size*6)
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*3, self.posy+self.size*5)
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*4, self.posy+self.size*6)
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*4, self.posy+self.size*4)
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*6, self.posy+self.size*4)
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*5, self.posy+self.size*3)
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*6, self.posy+self.size*2)
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*4, self.posy+self.size*2)
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*4, self.posy)
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*3, self.posy+self.size)
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*2, self.posy)
    kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*2, self.posy+self.size*2)
    kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy+self.size*2)
    kel.end_fill()

 # recursive function to draw repeating shape
def repeat_shape(self,intx, inty):
    if intx>=3 | inty>=3:
        return
    else:
        self.draw_shape(intx*180, inty*180)
        kel.right(90)
        self.repeat_shape(intx+1,inty)
        self.repeat_shape(intx,inty+1)

class image_play(object):
    def __init__(self,im_name):
        self.im_name = im_name

def rgb_to_gray_image(self):
    im = Image.open(self.im_name)
    im = im.convert('LA')

     # editing pixels of image to white
def loop_over_image(self):
    im = Image.open(self.im_name)
    width, height = im.size
    # nested loop over all pixels of image
    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            im[i][j] = 255;

kel.speed("fastest")

# object of class Draw_pattern
obj = Draw_pattern(0,0,30)
obj.draw_grid(0,0)
obj.repeat_shape(0,0)
```

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-8b7bbac27093> in <module>
    103 obj = Draw_pattern(0,0,30)
    104 obj.draw_grid(0,0)
--> 105 obj.repeat_shape(0,0)

AttributeError: 'Draw_pattern' object has no attribute 'repeat_shape'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the answer by @VasuDeo.S (+1) regarding your immediate problem.  However, I see some more subtle issues with your code:

- When it comes to your grid, your instructions say, "write a nested
  loop" but your two loops are *sequential* not *nested*.
- When working with turtle, `goto()` is used for large jumps (and to get out of jams).  For smaller movements, we tend to use `forward()`, `backward()`, `left()` and `right()` otherwise there's no difference between using turtle and a conventional line drawing graphics package.
- Your `self.posx` and `self.posy` instance variables serve no purpose beyond being convenient local variables.  They save no state that carries from one method to the other.  We can eliminate them as instance variables.
- It seems odd to have your object's instance methods rely on the global turtle named 'kel' -- it would make more sense to pass a turtle to its constructor or have it create one of its own.
- You can take more advantage of *symmetry* in your designs to reduce the amount of code you need to draw them.

I've addressed the above issues in my rework of your/Vasu's code below.  (I've left out your image code as that isn't currently active.)

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class DrawPattern():
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size

        self.turtle = Turtle()
        self.turtle.speed("fastest")

    def draw_grid(self, init_x, init_y):

        ''' Draw a grid '''

        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.goto(init_x, init_y)

        for _ in range(2):
            for _ in range(7):

                self.turtle.pendown()
                self.turtle.forward(self.size * 6)
                self.turtle.backward(self.size * 6)
                self.turtle.left(90)
                self.turtle.penup()
                self.turtle.forward(self.size)
                self.turtle.right(90)

            self.turtle.right(90)
            self.turtle.forward(self.size)

    def repeat_shape(self, iter_x, iter_y):
        if iter_x < 3 > iter_y:
            self.draw_shape(iter_x * 180, iter_y * 180)
            self.turtle.right(90)
            self.repeat_shape(iter_x + 1, iter_y)
            self.repeat_shape(iter_x, iter_y + 1)

    def draw_shape(self, init_x, init_y):

        ''' Recursive method to draw repeating shape '''

        # Draw yellow portion
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.goto(init_x, init_y)
        self.turtle.setheading(90)
        self.turtle.pendown()

        self.turtle.fillcolor("yellow")
        self.turtle.begin_fill()

        for _ in range(4):
            self.turtle.forward(self.size * 6)
            self.turtle.right(90)

        self.turtle.end_fill()

        # Draw red portion
        self.turtle.penup()
        self.turtle.goto(init_x, init_y + self.size * 2)
        self.turtle.setheading(0)
        self.turtle.pendown()

        self.turtle.fillcolor("red")
        self.turtle.begin_fill()

        for _ in range(4):
            self.turtle.left(45)
            self.turtle.forward(42)
            self.turtle.left(90)
            self.turtle.forward(42)
            self.turtle.right(135)
            self.turtle.forward(self.size * 2)
            self.turtle.left(90)
            self.turtle.forward(self.size * 2)
            self.turtle.left(180)

        self.turtle.end_fill()

# object instance of class DrawPattern
obj = DrawPattern(30)
obj.draw_grid(-200, -200)
obj.repeat_shape(0, 0)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import turtle
from PIL import Image
kel = turtle.Turtle()

class Draw_pattern(object):
    def __init__(self,posx,posy,size):
        self.posx = posx
        self.posy = posy
        self.size = size

    def draw_grid(self,initx, inity):
        # Drawing grid
        kel.penup()
        kel.color("black")
        for i in range(7):
            kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy)
            kel.pendown()
            kel.forward(self.size*6)
            self.posy = self.posy+self.size;
            self.posx = initx;
            kel.penup()

        self.posx = initx;
        self.posy = inity;
        kel.left(90)
        for i in range(7):
            kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy)
            kel.pendown()
            kel.forward(self.size*6)
            self.posx = self.posx+self.size;
            self.posy = inity;
            kel.penup()

    def repeat_shape(self, intx, inty):
        if intx>=3 | inty>=3:
            return
        else:
            self.draw_shape(intx*180, inty*180)
            kel.right(90)
            self.repeat_shape(intx+1, inty)
            self.repeat_shape(intx, inty+1)

    def draw_shape(self,initx, inity):
        self.posx = initx;
        self.posy = inity;
    # Drawing yellow portion
        kel.penup()
        kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy)
        kel.pendown()
        kel.fillcolor("yellow")
        kel.begin_fill()
        kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy+self.size*6)
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*6, self.posy+self.size*6)
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*6, self.posy)
        kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy)
        kel.end_fill()

    # Drawing red portion
        kel.penup()
        kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy+self.size*2)
        kel.pendown()
        kel.fillcolor("red")
        kel.begin_fill()
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size, self.posy+self.size*3)
        kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy+self.size*4)
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*2, self.posy+self.size*4)
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*2, self.posy+self.size*6)
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*3, self.posy+self.size*5)
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*4, self.posy+self.size*6)
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*4, self.posy+self.size*4)
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*6, self.posy+self.size*4)
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*5, self.posy+self.size*3)
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*6, self.posy+self.size*2)
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*4, self.posy+self.size*2)
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*4, self.posy)
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*3, self.posy+self.size)
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*2, self.posy)
        kel.goto(self.posx+self.size*2, self.posy+self.size*2)
        kel.goto(self.posx, self.posy+self.size*2)
        kel.end_fill()

        # recursive function to draw repeating shape


class image_play(object):
    def __init__(self,im_name):
        self.im_name = im_name

def rgb_to_gray_image(self):
    im = Image.open(self.im_name)
    im = im.convert('LA')

     # editing pixels of image to white
def loop_over_image(self):
    im = Image.open(self.im_name)
    width, height = im.size
    # nested loop over all pixels of image
    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(height):
            im[i][j] = 255;

kel.speed("fastest")

# object of class Draw_pattern
obj = Draw_pattern(0,0,30)
obj.draw_grid(0,0)
obj.repeat_shape(0, 0)
```

You declared some class function outside the class, and tried to call them as a class function, that caused the error.